# Sharing a set of XmlElementAttribute-decorated fields between types

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

Several of my XML-serializable types share the same set of properties, and I would like to  refactor them into a single type to remove the duplication as follows.

```
public class RequestHeader
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public string RequestId { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot]
public class RequestType
{
    public RequestHeader Header { get; set; }

    // ... other fields ...
}

[XmlRoot]
public class AnotherRequestType
{
    public RequestHeader Header { get; set; }

    // ... other fields ...
}
```

When serializing either of these types, the serializer encloses the contents of the `Header` property in a `<Header>` element.  Is there an attribute that may decorate the `Header` property such that the parent `<Header>` element is not rendered?  I've successfully accomplished this when serializing collection properties, but I wasn't sure if it could be done with a single element.

```
<RequestHeader>
    <Header>                         <!-- omit this -->
        <UserId>user</UserId>
        <RequestId>123</RequestId>
    </Header>                        <!-- omit this -->
</RequestHeader>
```

Alternatively, I can resort to inheritance or a collection with one element, but either of these options don't provide for a clean programming model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow up on this question, I ended up introducing a base class to store the common elements of my XML-serializable types.  After scanning the set of attributes that control XML-serializaion, and not finding a suitable mechanism, I concluded that this appears to be the only mechanism to solve the duplication issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you implement `IXmlSerializable` on `RequestHeader` class and write attributes using writer manually, without wrapping them in some outer tag.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `XmlSerializer` will still emit a wrapper element prior to invoking `WriteXml()` on `RequestHeader`.  I would have to implement `IXmlSerializable` on the request type too, which is a bit laborious.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately as I know you can not control it using attributes. One more idea is to replace composition with inheritance  making `RequestHeader` base class of all others.